# Using Phone Number to Prevent Spam: How to prevent spam on a mobile app?

Tags: user-interface, bots, user-experience, spam

Compared to using CAPTCHA, would using a phone number to prevent spam/bots improve the user experience.

I'm building an ecommerce app that does not require a user to create an account, when a user writes a product review they enter there phone number and a verification code is sent which the user sends back so that the review is successful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not typical to use CAPTCHA for a app login. The better UX for app users is to get the phone number and send a verification code to authenticate if the request is coming from a real user. When an SMS arrives it normally shows up at the top (on notification window) which shows the verification code at the top. So the user doesn't even have to switch the app to read the verification code in SMS. All he has to do is wait until the SMS arrives and key in the code in your app.

There are several SMS verification API providers available to make it easy for sending out verification code.

I have used [Nexmo Verify API](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/verify/verify) before which makes it easy to generate the code and completes the verification.

Comment: Thanks. Its not for the app login, but it is a requirement when you want to review a product so as to prevent someone from posting several positive reviews of their own product.